# What is the course content difference between conventional engineering and engineering technology programs?

Tags: engineering-history

I have seen institutions giving two different degrees to almost same courses. Some institutions give Bachelor/Master in engineering and some give Bachelor/master in Technology. So is their any underlying difference between Engineering and  Technology?  I am a student pursuing B-tech course. And in my semester subjects,  there is a subject humanities where we have to learn what's engineering and what's technology both!  But I didn't understand the difference as there is no such clear definition.

I have checked the Wikipedia articles and read the ABET definition of Engineering which says: The profession in which a knowledge of the mathematical and natural sciences gained by study, experiences and practices are applied with judgement to develop ways to utilize economically the materials and forces for the benefit of mankind. (Accreditation Board For Engineering And Technology, 2002)

But a Technologist also do the same thing. In what way are they different?  I have also checked the post for which it was informed as a duplicate post, and there the aspect on which they talked about is different from my question. I am not interested, being a technologist/engineer where will I get job. My question is specific to this point,  on what basis an **engineer and technologist are defined?  what are the extra things that an engineer do or technologist don't and the vice versa.**
I also checked the answers of that supposed original post,  the highest voted up answer has some basic faults. One thing I will like to mention technicians and technologist are **not the same** It was first defined in french and for completely different meaning. So I am looking for the particular differences an engineer and engineering has with technologist and technology.

Comment: "Technology" is engineering that becomes mainstream during the years when you're aged between 12 and 45. If it happens before you're 12, it's just the way the world works. And if happens after 45, it's against nature. But between 12 and 45, it's technology (H/T Feynman)

Comment: Also I would like you to request it to reopen so that people can answer. I checked the top voted answer &  the answers didn't give any particular answer to my question. Rather it was based on opinion of different college degrees. I did give reference of college degrees but as an example to make my question clear to the point of definition and difference. My question is clearly different than the question asked. Especially the person highlighted the differences in job and highlighted the difference in definition and work not salary and job though I agree they have similarities but not duplicate

Comment: I have again cleaned up the meta related comments on this question as they are detracting from the post.  Please do not use comments as a way of bypassing the review queues, moderator flags, or opening a question in [meta] to ask about the topicality of a post.